# Permanent Install of Relase Windows IoT App to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

My question is how do I permanently install/deploy my release version of a Windows IoT Core application to my Raspberry Pi SD Card?

I have written a little application that I am fairly happy with for now, so I want to be able to install so my Pi boots it on startup and it can be left to run for weeks on end if need be. Right now when I deploy release to the "Remote Device" option it disconnects when it has the network cable removed/visual studio is closed etc. basically it just acts as if it was still in debug.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've deployed it remotely via Visual Studio at least once, you should be able to set it by going to the Pi's Windows Device Portal (by navigating to `http://your-pi's-ip-address:8080` in your web browser). Once there, go to Apps -> Find your app in the list -> Select "Set as Default App".

Alternately, you can remote in with PowerShell:

- Open an Administrative PowerShell prompt on your computer.
- Start the WinRemoting service with `net start WinRM`.
- Add the Pi to WinRemoting's list of TrustedHosts: `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value <Pi's machine-name or IP Address>`.
- Now, start a remote session: `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName <Pi's machine-name or IP Address> -Credential <Pi's machine-name or IP Address>\Administrator`.
- It'll ask you for your Pi's password. If you left it as the default, it's `p@ssw0rd` (but I hope you didn't!)
- List your installed applications with `iotstartup list`.
- Find your app's App ID and use `iotstartup add headed <appid>` to set it as your startup app. If it's a headless app, you'd instead use `iotstartup add headless <appid>`.

Hope that helps!

Source for all this is on Microsoft's developer docs for IoT: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/setupdefaultapp

Comment: I used a web browser to connect to my Raspberry Pi with Windows 10 IoT. A small dialog popped up asking for username and password. Found elsewhere that the username is `Administrator` and now that I know that, I see it in the remote session start command but wasn't obvious to me.